# Скролл сообщений, как на vk.com

Tags: html, jquery, css

Как реализовать скроллинг сообщений, чтобы задействовался скролл основной страницы, а не скролл внутри блока?

Подходящий пример - сайт [vk.com](https://vk.com). Чтобы прокрутить историю сообщений, достаточно воспользоваться скроллом станицы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё очень просто: `position: fixed` для всех элементов, кроме тех, которые надо прокручивать. http://jsfiddle.net/zwkx8jhf/

Comment: Спасибо, работает