# Прокрутка div главным скроллом браузера

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Мне нужно сделать как здесь

http://jsfiddle.net/zGYvd/137/

Но этот скрипт отказывается работать вместе с `jQuery`, который у меня подключен. Можно его как-то поправить, чтоб работал? Или помогите на самом `jQuery` написать, если это не сложно

Консоль

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at get_style (scroll.js:123)
    at abs_pos (scroll.js:33)
    at (index):139
```

33 строка scroll.js

```
a['w']=parseInt(get_style(obj, 'width'));
```

123 строка scroll.js

```
if(!force && typeof(obj.style[name])!='undefined' && obj.style[name])
```

139 строка index

```
//Возвращает: координаты x/y, ширину, высоту элемента
        var el_xy=abs_pos(el_id);
```

Весь код здесь http://jsfiddle.net/zGYvd/137/

Comment: Андрей, что бы подправить, надо иметь представление, что у тебя там твориться.... Что в консоли браузера, какие ошибки, что именно не работает? Опиши вопрос нормально

Comment: jQuery ни как не влияет на этот код, вероятно проблема в другом.

Comment: @Максим если убрать jQuery то все работает

Comment: @air Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at get_style (scroll.js:123)
    at abs_pos (scroll.js:33)
    at (index):139

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Скролл сообщений, как на vk.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/422989)

Comment: @andreymal Но если всем элементам задать position:fixed тогда весь дизайн поплывёт

Comment: @АндрейДиневич значит плохой дизайн, если он от такого простого действия плывёт :)